# Parallelized compression libraries with API

Tags: c, file-compression

I have written a C application which uses [libbzip2](http://www.bzip.org) to compress and extract some statistical data.

The extraction times are excessive for large-scale datasets. Therefore, I am looking for C or C++ compression and extraction libraries which offer an API, preferably parallelized for multiprocessor or multicore systems.

Binaries like [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/), [pbzip2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/) and [lbzip2](http://lbzip2.org) perform parallelized compression and (to some extent) parallelized extraction, but do not seem to offer an API.

Are there projects which have turned these or other parallelized compression/extraction algorithms into usable APIs that can be integrated with C projects?